Why is increasing the "resolution" of a timer actually decreasing accuracy?
The central part of my App is a timer. Thus far this was the Code (taken out of the main Codebase to be minimum reproducible):
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    @State var countdownTimer = 5 * 60      /// The actual seconds of the timer, being counted down/up
    @State var timerRunning = false         /// Var to set and see if timer is running
    
    var body: some View {
        /// For formatting the timer numbers
        let style = Duration.TimeFormatStyle(pattern: .minuteSecond)
        let formTimer = Duration.seconds(countdownTimer).formatted()
        let formTimerShort = Duration.seconds(countdownTimer).formatted(style)
        
        /// The main Timer If there are no hours we hide the hour number and make the timer bigger in this way.
        Text(countdownTimer / 3600 == 0 && timerRunning ? "\(formTimerShort)" : "\(formTimer)")
            .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { _ in
                    if countdownTimer > 0 && timerRunning {
                        countdownTimer -= 1
                    } else {
                        timerRunning = false
                    }
            }
        
        /// The Start and Pause buttons
        HStack {
            if !timerRunning {
                Button(action: {
                    timerRunning = true
                }) {
                    Text("Start")
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 75)
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    timerRunning = false
                }) {
                    Text("Pause")
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 75)
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}

The problem with this was that it was not accurate. About 40 seconds of in 1 hour of timer usage. So my idea was to change when the Timer is published from 1 to 0.001, thus increasing the resolution. This Code works, but it is even less accurate!
struct TestView: View {

    @State var countdownTimer = 5 * 60      /// The actual seconds of the timer, being counted down/up
    @State private var fractionTimer = 0    /// Helping us to make the timer more accurate
    @State var timerRunning = false         /// Var to set and see if timer is running
    
    var body: some View {
        [...]
        
        /// The main Timer If there are no hours we hide the hour number and make the timer bigger in this way.
        Text(countdownTimer / 3600 == 0 && timerRunning ? "\(formTimerShort)" : "\(formTimer)")
            .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 0.001, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { _ in
                /// Count up the fraction timer, only if he hits a certain Number we count up our Visible Timer
                if timerRunning {
                    fractionTimer += 1
                }
                
                if fractionTimer == 1000 {
                    if countdownTimer > 0 && timerRunning {
                        countdownTimer -= 1
                        fractionTimer = 0
                    } else {
                        timerRunning = false
                        fractionTimer = 0
                    }
                }
            }

        [...]
    }
}

According to my logic this should have taken the inaccuracy from 40 seconds per hour to 0.04 seconds per hour. But actually it is now 120 seconds per hour off!
How can this be? Is it because it is running on the main thread and because it is called 1000 times a second there are many other tasks that will delay that call? Should I take it from the main thread?

I think you mean that it is less accurate at finer resolution. Precision refers to the granularity with which you measure something. Accuracy is how much error there is in your measurements. You are getting lower accuracy at higher precision.

Thank you Duncan, I edited the Question accordingly.

See my answer. I provided an updated version of your code that uses an end Date and math to figure out the remaining time.

I haven't worked much with timers in SwiftUI, but in gereral, you don't want to rely on timers to give you the exact number of calls that you ask for. (They will occasionally "skip a beat" if the system is busy at the moment the timer was supposed to fire.) You should use a Timer to update your UI, and then use math with the current Date and an end Date object to calculate the amount of time that has elapsed. (So go back to a timer that fires once/second, or a few times a second, but calculate the number of seconds remaining based on the current Date each time the timer fires.)
Consider this variation of your code, which will not lose seconds:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var startDate = Date()       /// For a countUp timer, the date the timer was started
    @State var endDate = Date()         /// For a count down timer, the Date when the timer will end.
    var totalSeconds: Int               /// For a countdown timer, the number of seconds to count.
    @State var timerSeconds: Int        /// The actual seconds of the timer, being counted down/up
    @State var timerRunning = false     /// Var to set and see if timer is running
    @State var countUp: Bool = false    /// True if the timer is counting up, false if counting down.

    init(totalSeconds: Int, countUp: Bool = false) {
        self.totalSeconds = totalSeconds
        self.countUp = countUp
        if countUp {
            self.timerSeconds = 0
        } else {
            self.timerSeconds = totalSeconds
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Spacer()
            /// For formatting the timer numbers
            let style = Duration.TimeFormatStyle(pattern: .minuteSecond)
            let formTimer = Duration.seconds(timerSeconds).formatted()
            let formTimerShort = Duration.seconds(timerSeconds).formatted(style)
            
            /// The main Timer If there are no hours we hide the hour number and make the timer bigger in this way.
            Text(timerSeconds < 3600 ? "\(formTimerShort)" : "\(formTimer)")
                .font(.system(size: 42))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(countUp || timerSeconds > 0 ? .blue : .red)
                .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { _ in
                    if timerRunning {
                        if countUp {
                            timerSeconds = Int(round(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) - startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)

                        } else {
                            timerSeconds = Int(round(endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))
                            if timerSeconds <= 0 {
                                timerRunning = false
                            } else {
                                timerSeconds = Int(round(endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: countUp) {
                    if countUp {
                        timerSeconds = 0
                    } else {
                        timerSeconds = totalSeconds
                    }
                }
            /// The Start and Pause buttons
            if !timerRunning {
                Button(action: {
                    if countUp {
                        startDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(-timerSeconds))
                    } else {
                        endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(timerSeconds))
                    }
                    timerRunning = true
                }) {
                    Text("Start")
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 75)
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    timerRunning = false
                }) {
                    Text("Pause")
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 75)
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                if countUp {
                    timerSeconds = 0
                    startDate = Date()
                } else {
                    timerSeconds = totalSeconds
                    endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(timerSeconds))
                }
            }) {
                Text("Reset")
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 75)
                    .font(.system(size: 60))
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Toggle("Count up", isOn: $countUp)
                    .frame(width: 150)
                    .disabled(timerRunning)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView(totalSeconds: 5 * 60, countUp: false)
}


Note that the above approach makes it possible to keep track of your timer while your app is suspended. (Since you record the end date at which the timer should go off, and the device's clock continues to advance even if your app is not getting timer change notifications. If you want your timer to pause when in the background, you could set up an @Environment scenePhase variable, and when you detect a switch to the inactive phase, set timerRunning=false.

You can't really say your timer will "keep running" when your app is suspended because you won't get any events. Thus if the timer goes off while you are suspended you won't be able to report it to the user until they switch back. To fix that you'd probably want to set up a local notification for your timer's endDate. local notifications are managed by the system and fire even if your app is suspended

Thank you so much it works perfectly! Why did you choose 0.25 as a publish interval and not 1? Would it otherwise be jumping around with the seconds as the timer might not hit exactly the correct second? And how is iOS Date() so exact? Did apple built in extra hardware for their clock and we use that? Or is it connected to a server? If so would it be less accurate in flight mode?

That the timer runs also in background is actually perfect. What you are talking about is actually a big problem I was contemplating. Either to run it as a background task or to use a live widget to solve that problem to notify the user in the end. Thank you so much for this third solution using Notification, could that also execute some code or play a sound?

And actually another function of my timer was to count up. I tried to change the minus into a plus in the date calculation, but that didn't work at all. But I am sure tomorrow (Im in Europe) it will not take long to understand fully this Date() approach. Thank you so much again Duncan.

As to your questions, I had the publish interval of .25 seconds when I was using a counter that was a Double. With an Int secondsRemaining there's not much point. A publish interval of 1 second should work fine. The Date() function is tied to the system clock, which is microsecond-accurate, and driven by the device's quartz crystal.

Local notifications can be set to fire at some future date/time. They display a notification to the user, and can optionally play a sound. They will also wake up your app if it's suspended or even re-launch if it was terminated.

I edited the code to support timers that count up or down. It's a bit hacky since I didn't write it that way to begin with, but it works.

The inaccuracy is probably because the timer is lost every time it fires and the issue is compounded because of the misuse of onChange. To prevent it being lost the timer publisher needs to be a state, eg

@State var timer: Publisher? = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var isRunning: Bool {
    timer != nil
}

…

.onReceive(timer)


onChange is for external actions not for updating state. The state should already have the correct value before body is called.
Also the if inside body breaks SwiftUIs identity cause extra heap allocations and slows it down. You should have a single Button declaration and use if inside its params.

This should be a comment, not an answer.

Would be a very long comment to fix all your bad SwiftUI

I used the OP's code and did not make any attempt to clean it up. The fact remains that your "answer" does not address the root problem, which is that you should not rely on timers to fire every single interval. They run on the run loop they are attached to, and if that run loop doesn't get visited frequently enough, they "skip beats." I showed how to modify the OPs code to instead do math with Dates to reliably calculate the amount of elapsed time.

(I didn't down-vote your answer BTW.)
